# PortableText in Sanity v3

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I started using PortableText for sanity v3 and I am struggling to understand the components options.

From the documentation it is unclear to me what is the difference between block:{} and types:{} ? I ended up styling my text using block only because I didnt know what to put inside of the component in the types.

My working code example

```
<PortableText
            value={actuality?.text}
            key={index}
            components={{
              block: {
                normal: (props) => {
                  return <Text center>{props.children}</Text>;
                },
              },
              types: {
                 block: (props) => {
                   return <h1 style={{ color: "red" }}>???WHAT SHOULD I RETURN HERE FOR PARAGRAPH ELEMENT</h1>;
                 },
               },
            }}
          />
```

My questions are:

1. What am I supposed to write inside of the types to make the component work? I tried {props.value.text} and {props.children}
   and both of which threw error.
2. What are the differences between block option in components and types option? Give me an example please.